# SQL server Sub string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

could you please help in getting the below sub string.

I have values like

```
1.1
1.10.1
1.2.2.1
```

expected output (need to exclude the digits after the second dot)

```
1.1
1.10
1.2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of sql server are you on?

Comment: SELECT LEFT(yourstring, CHARINDEX('.', yourstring, CHARINDEX('.', yourstring)+1)-1);

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach that demonstrates the use of a CROSS APPLY and a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1.1')
,('1.10.1')
,('1.2.2.1')

Select A.* 
      ,NewValue=concat(
               XMLData.value('/x[1]','varchar(50)')
               ,'.'+XMLData.value('/x[2]','varchar(50)')
               )
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (  values (Cast('<x>' + replace(SomeCol,'.','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) ) B(XMLData)
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol   NewValue
1.1       1.1
1.10.1    1.10
1.2.2.1   1.2
```

**EDIT - Just another option using `parsename()`**

```
Select A.* 
      ,NewValue=reverse(parsename(reverse(SomeCol),2)
              +'.'
              +parsename(reverse(SomeCol),1)
              )
From  @YourTable A
```

Comment: SELECT LEFT(yourstring, CHARINDEX('.', yourstring, CHARINDEX('.', yourstring)+1)-1);

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much

Comment: `reverse`... that is a sneaky way of shoehorning `parsename()` into this. I love it. I was trying to make `STRING_SPLIT()` and `STRING_AGG()` to work here, but there is no way to guarantee order in the output which is a HUGE disappointment.

Comment: @JNevill Ups, i answered it this way, in SqlFiddle it looked fine...

Comment: @Turo string_split() may work 99.9999% of the time with a small sample, but there is no GTD of the sequence.  This is a tragic omission from string_split().

Answer (score 0):

Simplest appraoch is to use with combination of `LEFT()` & `CHARINDEX()` :

```
SELECT LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('.', col + '.', CHARINDEX('.', col + '.') + 1 ) - 1)
FROM table t;
```

Comment: this wont work for 1st string (1.1) where you have olny 1 occurence of .

Comment: LEFT(TV_AB_Name, case when CHARINDEX('.', TV_AB_Name, CHARINDEX('.', TV_AB_Name)+1) = 0 then len(TV_AB_Name) else CHARINDEX('.', TV_AB_Name, CHARINDEX('.', TV_AB_Name)+1) - 1 end )

Comment: please review and confirm

Comment: @Surya. .  You don't need case expression for this. Use `LEFT(TV_AB_Name, CHARINDEX('.', TV_AB_Name + '.', CHARINDEX('.', TV_AB_Name + '.') + 1 ) - 1)`

Comment: For my requirement the logic without case is not working. the one with case which i sent is working fine. Thank you very much